# What it mean when your pull request is okay but are asked to "rebase this on master?" After which the owner will merge it

Tags: git, github

Your pull request is approved by someone with write permissions, and they respond "can you rebase this on master? I'll merge it after."

What would be the steps using git, if that simplifies things. Or any step involving Visual Studio and even GitHub Desktop.

- git rebase master
- git commit -m "rebased to master"
- git push

Is that what he meant? And why would my fork need to be rebased? I can't possibly rebase his repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first to reference the target repository, assuming your PR comes from a fork:

```sh
cd /path/to/local/cloned/fork
git remote add upstream https://github.com/original/repository
git fetch upstream
```

Then you can rebase on top of the updated target branch (`master`) from the target repository (`upstream`)

```sh
git switch my_pr_branch
git rebase upstream/master
git push --force
```

Assuming you are the only one working on the PR, the push --force is not dangerous, and will update your PR.

The end goal is to allow the maintainer of the target repository to do a trivial merge of your PR branch to master: trivial because all your PR commits will have been added on top of master, there is no more merge conflicts.
Any merge conflicts were resolved locally, by you, during the rebase.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed a PR from a fork. I just realized I merged the master into my forked branch. Let me try to undo that and try your well written answer.

Comment: I don't have wire permissions, so it seems to be back in a new review state. Thank you though. Trying this took hours... many unexpected messages, figuring out how to navigate this repo idea.

Comment: I stumbled at the `rebase` step with git turning yellow hinting: `hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".`

Comment: @LouisWaweru Yes, that is expcted: the rebase means: resolve any merge conflict locally. Hence, your yellow hint message.

Comment: The fetch caught up about 20 new commits, it was a bit daunting. Ah, conflict must mean a file that I have changed too. Not the other commits I didn't touch. Less scary if so

Comment: @LouisWaweru That is a natural consequence of decentralized version control: asynchronous and concurrent development. While you are developing on your fork, the original repository keep receiving new commits.